# Multiple products in one form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I would like to add a functionality in my form, in which a user can add as many entries before hitting `submit button`, like a `'add to cart'` functionality, show the added entries in same page, in a separate `div` with `submit button` then save those multiple entry in database using that submit button(in a separate `div` that shows added entry).

So far my form allows only entries on per submit bases, meaning is if the user wants to add another entry, he/she has to go back to the form and add and click to submit again.

```
<form method="POST" name="myForm" action="saveto.php">
  <label> Speed Rating:</label>
  <select name="speed_rating" required class="form-control" id="speed_rating" ></select>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label> Description:</label>
    <select name="description" required class="form-control" id="description" >
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label> Load Index:</label>
   <select name="load_index" required class="form-control" id="load_index" >
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label> Vendor:</label>
   <select name="vendor" required class="form-control" id="vendor" >
  </select>
  <div class="note"> Recommended Vendor : <span id="recomvend"> </span> </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label> Quantity:</label>
  <input type="text" required name="qty" class="form-control" id="qty"></div>       
  <div style="clear:both"> </div>   
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary smp" value="Submit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
  <button id="clear"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary smp smp2" > Reset </button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

How would you achieved this? My `saveto.php` is just a normal script that will process the submitted data to database, one entry in a per submit bases.

Comment: You will need to create new form inputs on the client side as well as controls to create them, and update your server side code to handle them.  Check out the **[]** notation for naming inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jy6vh4rp/31/

If that's what you are looking for then you should add this to your front end:

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
  <div style="padding: 30px 0; text-align: center;">
    <button type="button" onclick="createDOM()">Add</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
  </div>
  <div class="productsContainer"></div>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    id = 0;
    createDOM = function() {
      $(".productsContainer").append('<input type="text" id="' + id + '" name="products[]" value="' + id + '" />');
     id++;
    };
  });
</script>
```

And this to your validation backend :

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $prodInput){ 
  $product = filter_var($prodInput,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  if( is_numeric($product) ){
    echo $product;  
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dagon Agreed. it may be useful if they decide to validate using javascript some time later

Comment: @Braza, I edited my question, I realised I need to create select tags for the form

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga what do you mean by select tags? a select/option form element or a tag selector?

Comment: I mean select/option form element

Comment: I need to show all added field's value in a separate div before submitting it

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you want please? the select will hold your products? named by ID? anything should change on user selecting an element? is it a multiple or single option selector? a Jsfiddle or a [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/) would be a great help.

Comment: As I see it, this is a separate or new question, please do validate this one as is and create a new one with your new request. This will keep this one for those who are looking for answers to your initial question

Comment: Ok I will create a new question for this

Comment: @Braza I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399667/show-added-values-on-same-page-before-submitting-in-form-with-multiple-entry