# Show Added Values on same page before submitting in form with multiple entry

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to add functionality to my existing form.So far my form allows only entries on per submit bases, meaning is if the user wants to add another entry, he/she has to go back to the form and add and click to submit again.I would like to show all added values on same page, cause I am planning to add a Javascript print function that will print the add entries before saving to database.I need all values in fields to be printed

```
<form method="POST" name="myForm" action="saveto.php">
  <label> Speed Rating:</label>
  <select name="speed_rating" required class="form-control" id="speed_rating" ></select>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
    <label> Description:</label>
    <select name="description" required class="form-control" id="description" >
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label> Load Index:</label>
   <select name="load_index" required class="form-control" id="load_index" >
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label> Vendor:</label>
   <select name="vendor" required class="form-control" id="vendor" >
  </select>
  <div class="note"> Recommended Vendor : <span id="recomvend"> </span> </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label> Quantity:</label>
  <input type="text" required name="qty" class="form-control" id="qty"></div>       
  <div style="clear:both"> </div>   
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary smp" value="Submit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
  <button id="clear"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary smp smp2" > Reset </button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

   entry 1

    speed rating -- 46
    description ---'the discription'
    ------

   entry 2
   speed rating --56
   description  ---'another description'

   submit
```

The `saveto.php` is just a normal script that will process the submitted data to database, one entry in a per submit bases.